# Hbase insert are very slow when kafka avro records are converted to Json

Tags: scala, hbase, spark-streaming, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka 10 and receiving records in it from DB2 CDC. Kafka 10 uses Confluent Schema Registry to store the DB2 table schema and sends the records as Avro `Array[Byte]`. I want to store these records into `Hbase` (lets say Raw Hbase) and then run some transformation over those new records(like dropping columns, aggregation etc) using Hive and store the transformed records again into Hbase (lets say conformed Hbase). I tried 2 approaches and both are giving me some kind of issues. The records are big in length with ~500 columns(although only 10% of columns are req.) and each record is of size ~10kb.

1) I tried deserializing the records into `Array[Byte]` and then use the `streamBulkPut` method to insert it into Hbase.

Deserializer code:

```
def toRecord(buffer: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
var schemaRegistry: SchemaRegistryClient = null
schemaRegistry= new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(url, 10)
val bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer)
bb.get() // consume MAGIC_BYTE
val schemaId = bb.getInt // consume schemaId //println(schemaId.toString)
val schema = schemaRegistry.getByID(schemaId) // consult the Schema Registry //println(schema)
val reader = new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord](schema)
val decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(buffer, bb.position(), bb.remaining(), null)
val writer = new GenericDatumWriter[GenericRecord](schema)
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
val jsonEncoder = EncoderFactory.get.jsonEncoder(schema, baos)
writer.write( reader.read(null, decoder), jsonEncoder) //reader.read(null, decoder): returns Generic record
jsonEncoder.flush
baos.toByteArray
}
```

HBase bulkPut code:

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[Object,Array[Byte],KafkaAvroDecoder,DefaultDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet)
val hconf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
val hbaseContext = new HBaseContext(ssc.sparkContext, hconf)
val tableName = "your_table"
var rowKeyArray: Array[String] = null
hbaseContext.streamBulkPut(messages,TableName.valueOf(tableName),putFunction)
def putFunction(avroRecord:Tuple2[Object,Array[Byte]]):Put = {
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  val recordKey = getKeyString(parse(avroRecord._1.toString.mkString).extract[Map[String,String]].values.mkString)
  var put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(recordKey))
  put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("row"), AvroDeserializer.toRecord(avroRecord._2))
  put
}
def getKeyString(keystr:String):String = {
(Math.abs(keystr map (_.hashCode) reduceLeft( 31 * _ + _) ) % 10 + 48).toChar + "_"  + keystr.trim
}
```

Now this method works but the inserts are painfully slow. I am getting a throughput of ~5k records per minute. The plan was once the records are in Raw Hbase I will use Hive to read and explode the json to run the transformation.

2) Instead of re-serializing the records while storing into Raw Hbase I thought of doing it while loading from Raw->Conformed Hbase (I can manage the slowness here as the data will be already with me i.e. out of kafka). So I tried storing Avro records as it is into Hbase and it ran very fast, I was able to insert 1.5 Million records in 2 mins. Below is code:

```
 hbaseContext.streamBulkPut(messages,TableName.valueOf(tableName),putFunction)
def putFunction(avroRecord:Tuple2[Object,Array[Byte]]):Put = {
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val recordKey = parse(avroRecord._1.toString.mkString).extract[Map[String,String]]
var put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(getKeyString(recordKey.values.mkString)))
put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("row"), avroRecord._2)
put
}
```

The problem with this approach is Hive is not able to read Avro records from Hbase and I cannot filter the records/run any logic on it.

I would appreciate any kind of help or resource that I can follow to improve the performance. Any approach would work for me if its corresponding issue is solved. Thanks

Comment: 1) Did you perform measurements and profiling? 2) Did you try https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-AvroDataStoredinHBaseColumns.1 ?

Comment: I tried the option 2 however my schema length is too big and apparently Hive only allows 4000 Chars of schema. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098596/issue-hive-avroserde-tblproperties-max-length

Comment: I am not sure about Measurements and profiling, can you please provide some resources related to it?

Comment: For example using jvisualvm or debug logging with times. It's needed to localize bottleneck.